# how to add icon in a datagrid in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add icons inside a datagrid in a specific column.
But I don't even know if it's possible. If so, I want to use  inside 'Role' column. I don't know how the implement it inside a datagrid. I searched in the web, but didn't get anything that helps me. So kindly help me figure this out.

this is my code

```
    function DataGridExample() {
    const [platform, setPlatform] = useState([]);
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let platformList = [
            { id: 1, role: 'Sender', counter_party: "Bharath", token: "1.000", date:"16-03-2022 06:20 AM", comments:'Test First Transfer' },
            { id: 2, role: "Sender", counter_party: "Harish", token: "1.000" , date:"14-03-2022 08:59 AM", comments:'Testing from hosted'},
            { id: 3, role: "Receiver", counter_party: "Vijay", token: "1.000", date:"14-03-2022 08:53 AM", comments:'Test First Transfer'},
        ];
        setPlatform(platformList);
        setRows(platformList);
    }, []);
    const columns = [
        { field: 'role', headerName: 'Role', width: 150,},
        { field: 'counter_party', headerName: 'Counter Party', width: 200 },
        { field: 'token', headerName: 'Token', width: 150 },
        { field: 'date', headerName: 'Date', width: 200 },
        { field: 'comments', headerName: 'Comments', width: 200 }

    ];
    function escapeRegExp(value) {
        return value.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
    }
    const requestSearch = (searchValue) => {
        const searchRegex = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(searchValue), 'i');
        const filteredRows = platform.filter((row) => {
            return Object.keys(row).some((field) => {
                return searchRegex.test(row[field].toString());
            });
        });
        setRows(filteredRows);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                <Box>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        size='small'
                        value={searchText}
                        onChange={(e) => { setSearchText(e.target.value); requestSearch(e.target.value) }}
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        InputProps={{
                            startAdornment: <SearchIcon fontSize="small" color="action" />,
                            endAdornment: (
                                <IconButton
                                    title="Clear"
                                    aria-label="Clear"
                                    size="small"
                                    style={{ visibility: searchText ? 'visible' : 'hidden', borderRadius: "57%", paddingRight: "1px", margin: "0", fontSize: "1.25rem" }}
                                    onClick={(e) => { setSearchText(''); setRows(platform) }}
                                >
                                    <ClearIcon fontSize="small" color="action" />
                                </IconButton>
                            ),
                        }}
                    />
                </Box>
                <DataGrid
                    disableColumnMenu
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                    pageSize={10}
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                />
            </div>
        </div >
    );
}
export { DataGridExample };
```

this is how my table currently looks like
[image]

and this is how I want my table to be
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add custom renderCell in column

this is how i do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKoxN.png)

Comment: Please take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and don't post code as pictures but copy and paste it, using the formatting possibilities we provide.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following to insert a material-ui icon in your datagrid.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { FormControlLabel, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import { blue } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

    const MatEdit = ({ index }) => {

        const handleEditClick = () => {
            // some action
        }


        return <FormControlLabel
                   control={
                       <IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="add an alarm" onClick={handleEditClick} >
                           <EditIcon style={{ color: blue[500] }} />
                       </IconButton>
                   }
               />
    };

    const MyComponent= () => {
          const rows = [{ id: 1, name: "ABC", email: "xyz@gmail.com" }];
          const columns=[
                    { field: "name", headerName: "Name" }, 
                    { field: "email", headerName: "Email" },
                    {
                        field: "actions",
                        headerName: "Actions",
                        sortable: false,
                        width: 140,
                        disableClickEventBubbling: true,
                        renderCell: (params) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                                    <MatEdit index={params.row.id} />
                                 </div>
                            );
                         }
                      }
                  ];

          return (
             <div style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}>
                 <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
             </div>
          )
};

export default MyComponent;
```

[Click here for a sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-forked-lg5vu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add icons.

```
{
  field: 'actions',
  type: 'actions',
  getActions: (params: GridRowParams) => [
    <GridActionsCellItem icon={...} onClick={...} label="Delete" />,
    <GridActionsCellItem icon={...} onClick={...} label="Print" showInMenu />,
  ]
}
```

Resources: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/

My example

```
{
  field: "saveDelete",
  headerAlign: "center",
  headerName: "Save/Delete",
  align: "center",
  flex: 1.5,
  type: "actions",
  getActions: (params) => [
    <GridActionsCellItem
      icon={<GridAddIcon />}
      label="Save"
      onClick={saveRow(params.row)}
    />,
    <GridActionsCellItem
      icon={<GridDeleteIcon />}
      label="Delete"
      onClick={deleteRow(params.row)}
    />,
  ],
},
```

You can import the icons as follows.

```
import {   GridActionsCellItem,
  GridAddIcon,
  GridDeleteIcon,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
```

You can see the list of the Slots here

https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#DataGrid-css-null

I am using V 6.18